# Operator Overloader with a card class with vector sort

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, operator-overloading

I want  to be able to sort a vector of a "card" class using the sort function like so:

```
struct Card 
{
    int Number;
    char Suit;
};

vector<Card> hand;
std::sort (hand.begin(), hand.end());
```

So i overloaded the < operator for the card class so see if this would allow sort to work, but I am getting an error while comparing the "Number" variables. (Number is undefined).

```
bool operator < (const Card); 

 bool Card::operator < (const Card ob) 
{

if (Number < ob.Number){
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}
```

First, I want to make sure if this will even allow sort to work, and second, I would like some advice as to how to get Num to compare correctly

Answer (score 1):

The data member is called `Number`, not `Num`.

While you're at it, change the operator to take the argument by reference:

```
bool Card::operator < (const Card& ob) 
                                 ^ THIS
```

Finally, the entire `if` can be succinctly expressed as

```
return (Num < ob.Num);
```

Comment: Even more succinctly without the redundant parentheses. <g>

Comment: Number is still not initialized in the scope of the boolean operator. I think this is because Num is only in the scope of the Card structure. How do I reference the first Num variable in the return statement?

Comment: @user2105982: Either this is a member function, and you don't have to, or it's not a member function and you need to take _two_ arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will work, but you need to use `Number`

```
bool Card::operator < (const Card& ob) 
{
  return (Number < ob.Number) ;
}
```

`Number` is what you've used as  member in your struct `Card`

Answer (score 0):

The name of the corresponding data member is Number  not Num.

The correct declaration and definition of the operator will look as

```
bool operator < ( const Card & ) const; 

bool Card::operator < ( const Card &ob ) const
{
    return Number < ob.Number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have `Number` member in your `Card` class, not `Num`.
refactor

```
struct Card 
{
    int Number;
    char Suit;
};
```

to

```
struct Card 
{
    int Num;
    char Suit;
};
```

or change function (and take argument by reference regardless if you refactor class or function body):

```
bool Card::operator < (const Card& ob) 
                                 ^
                              use reference 
{
  return (Number < ob.Number) ;  //this will replace correctly your if condition
            ^           ^
}
```